# Should I use pointer to std::string

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, std

In learning c++, I first use Qt library instead of the standard C++, STL and all that (Ok, so I'm new with c++ and spoiled by Qt). On Qt, QString used implicit sharing, thus enabling me to just copy assign it to another variable like:

```
QString var1=QString("Hi there!");
QString var2=var1
```

And that would do nicely without much overhead. But now, i'm trying std::string so, should I do

```
std::string var1=std::string()
```

or

```
std::string* var1=new std::string()
```

And also, how about QVector and std::vector. And If I do have to use the pointer... any tips?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether `std::string` uses copy-on-write depends on the implementation (i.e. your standard library vendor decides that). However, most `std::string` implementations will not use COW, largely due to the fact that most if not all read operations force a copy -- `operator[]` returns a reference, `c_str()` and `data()` return a pointer. Compare this to `QString::operator[]`, which returns a proxy object.

In spite of the above, don't use pointers to `std::string`,  unless you determine (by measuring) that string copies are the bottleneck in your application.

Also, beware that `QString` stores UTF-16 strings, whereas `std::string` stores a sequence of `char`s -- [`QByteArray`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qbytearray.html) would be the Qt equivalent.

Comment: std::string is not allowed to do COW anymore (C++11), since it would invalidate iterators.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::string var1("Hi there!");
std::string var2=var1;
```

**[std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)** class has an `=` operator defined as:

```
string& operator= ( const string& str );
```

Comment: In this, the copy constructor should be called and not copy assignment?

Answer (score 2):

```
std::string* var1=new std::string()
```

Don't do that. Just pass it by reference wherever possible:

```
void f(const std::string& s); // no copying
```

If you really need to share the string, use:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::string> var1 = std::make_shared<std::string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to return `std::string` from function then don't use pointer - return by value. In this case most likely [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) will be applied and string data will not be copied.